# MariaDB having different performance on similiar tables with same indices

Tags: sql, node.js, performance, indexing, mariadb

I'm currently trying to optimize performance in an application which uses a MariaDB (v10.5.10). When I analyze the low performing query the ANALYZE statement is confusing me by having longer execution time in specific blocks than expected.

The CREATE statement of the relevant tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `position` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `comment` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `version` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1692
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `position_info` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `position_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bezeichnung` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `location` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `bereich` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `valid_from` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `valid_to` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `updated_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `deleted_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `version` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `position_info_position_idx` (`position_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `position_info_created_idx` (`created_by`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `position_info_updated_idx` (`updated_by`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `position_info_deleted_idx` (`deleted_by`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `pi_valid_from_index` (`position_id`, `valid_from`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `position_info_created_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `db`.`user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `position_info_deleted_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`deleted_by`) REFERENCES `db`.`user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `position_info_position_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`position_id`) REFERENCES `db`.`position` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `position_info_updated_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `db`.`user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

A shortened version of the SQL query with the low performance (2172ms total).

```
SELECT `positionInfo`.*
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT `id`, `position_id` AS `positionId`, `bezeichnung`, `location`, `bereich`, `valid_from` AS `validFrom`, `valid_to` AS `validTo`, `created_by` AS `createdBy`, `updated_by` AS `updatedBy`, `deleted_by` AS `deletedBy`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `version`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `deleted_at` AS `deletedAt`
FROM `position_info` AS `positionInfo`
WHERE (`positionInfo`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ((`positionInfo`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `positionInfo`.`valid_from` <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'))) AND `positionInfo`.`position_id` = 256
ORDER BY `validFrom` DESC
LIMIT 1) AS sub UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT `id`, `position_id` AS `positionId`, `bezeichnung`, `location`, `bereich`, `valid_from` AS `validFrom`, `valid_to` AS `validTo`, `created_by` AS `createdBy`, `updated_by` AS `updatedBy`, `deleted_by` AS `deletedBy`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `version`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `deleted_at` AS `deletedAt`
FROM `position_info` AS `positionInfo`
WHERE (`positionInfo`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ((`positionInfo`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `positionInfo`.`valid_from` <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'))) AND `positionInfo`.`position_id` = 18
ORDER BY `validFrom` DESC
LIMIT 1) AS sub UNION ALL
...
```

The query is generated by Sequelize, a JavaScript ORM, as a separate query to a more complex query. Since the where statement uses both the position_id and valid_from fields I created the pi_valid_from_index which is a composite index over both fields.

When I analyze it it yields the following result:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 1809.757232,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "<derived2>",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 350,
      "r_rows": 171,
      "r_table_time_ms": 0.46998943,
      "r_other_time_ms": 0.151807862,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "materialized": {
        "query_block": {
          "union_result": {
            "table_name": "<union2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,114,116,...>",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "r_loops": 0,
            "r_rows": null,
            "query_specifications": [
              {
                "query_block": {
                  "select_id": 2,
                  "r_loops": 1,
                  "r_total_time_ms": 16.59932409,
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "<derived3>",
                    "access_type": "ALL",
                    "r_loops": 1,
                    "rows": 2,
                    "r_rows": 1,
                    "r_table_time_ms": 0.044354854,
                    "r_other_time_ms": 0.01983318,
                    "filtered": 100,
                    "r_filtered": 100,
                    "materialized": {
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 3,
                        "r_loops": 1,
                        "r_total_time_ms": 0.10711399,
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "positionInfo",
                          "access_type": "range",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "position_info_position_idx",
                            "pi_valid_from_index"
                          ],
                          "key": "pi_valid_from_index",
                          "key_length": "11",
                          "used_key_parts": ["position_id", "valid_from"],
                          "r_loops": 1,
                          "rows": 1,
                          "r_rows": 1,
                          "r_table_time_ms": 0.028658321,
                          "r_other_time_ms": 0.019230482,
                          "filtered": 100,
                          "r_filtered": 100,
                          "attached_condition": "positioninfo.position_id <=> 256 and positioninfo.deleted_at is null and positioninfo.deleted_at is null and positioninfo.valid_from <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "query_block": {
                  "select_id": 4,
                  "operation": "UNION",
                  "r_loops": 1,
                  "r_total_time_ms": 11.18885812,
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "<derived5>",
                    "access_type": "ALL",
                    "r_loops": 1,
                    "rows": 2,
                    "r_rows": 1,
                    "r_table_time_ms": 0.040932656,
                    "r_other_time_ms": 0.01641161,
                    "filtered": 100,
                    "r_filtered": 100,
                    "materialized": {
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 5,
                        "r_loops": 1,
                        "r_total_time_ms": 0.097741398,
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "positionInfo",
                          "access_type": "range",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "position_info_position_idx",
                            "pi_valid_from_index"
                          ],
                          "key": "pi_valid_from_index",
                          "key_length": "11",
                          "used_key_parts": ["position_id", "valid_from"],
                          "r_loops": 1,
                          "rows": 1,
                          "r_rows": 1,
                          "r_table_time_ms": 0.025234867,
                          "r_other_time_ms": 0.020159014,
                          "filtered": 100,
                          "r_filtered": 100,
                          "attached_condition": "positioninfo.position_id <=> 18 and positioninfo.deleted_at is null and positioninfo.deleted_at is null and positioninfo.valid_from <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
...
```

The db is using the index as expected. As seen the r_total_time_ms of the middle block is ca. 10ms on most blocks but the time of the deeper ones doesn't add up to that. I know that there can be also causes like other things happening on the db but it is tested on test db with no extra traffic.

What confuses me the most is that there is a second similiar query on a similiar table which has similiar r_total_time_ms in the deeper blocks but a way shorter time in the middle blocks. I have added the same info for the second table that works faster below.

Another thing that suprised me is that the performance stays the same even without the composite index when it only uses the index over the position_id. Adding the index to the second table improved the performance from ca. 80 ms to 7ms.

The CREATE statement of the relevant tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `aircraft` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `registration` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `version` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `aircraft_created_idx` (`created_by`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `aircraft_created_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `db`.`user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `aircraft_assignment` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `aircraft_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `airline_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `class` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `category` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `valid_from` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `valid_to` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `version` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `aircraft_assignment_aircraft_idx` (`aircraft_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `aircraft_assignment_airline_idx` (`airline_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `aircraft_assignment_created_idx` (`created_by`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `aa_valid_from_index` (`aircraft_id`, `valid_from`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `aircraft_assignment_aircraft_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`aircraft_id`) REFERENCES `db`.`aircraft` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `aircraft_assignment_airline_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`airline_id`) REFERENCES `db`.`airline` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `aircraft_assignment_created_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `db`.`user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

A shortened version of the SQL query that performs better (31ms total)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT `id`, `aircraft_id` AS `aircraftId`, `airline_id` AS `airlineId`, `type`, `class`, `category`, `created_by` AS `createdBy`, `valid_from` AS `validFrom`, `valid_to` AS `validTo`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `version`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `deleted_at` AS `deletedAt`
FROM `aircraft_assignment` AS `aircraftAssignment`
WHERE (`aircraftAssignment`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ((`aircraftAssignment`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `aircraftAssignment`.`valid_from` <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'))) AND `aircraftAssignment`.`aircraft_id` = 'd27feb20-7de9-4500-b0a5-9965aa9fb80a'
ORDER BY `validFrom` DESC
LIMIT 1) AS sub UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT `id`, `aircraft_id` AS `aircraftId`, `airline_id` AS `airlineId`, `type`, `class`, `category`, `created_by` AS `createdBy`, `valid_from` AS `validFrom`, `valid_to` AS `validTo`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`, `version`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `deleted_at` AS `deletedAt`
FROM `aircraft_assignment` AS `aircraftAssignment`
WHERE (`aircraftAssignment`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ((`aircraftAssignment`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `aircraftAssignment`.`valid_from` <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'))) AND `aircraftAssignment`.`aircraft_id` = 'de648ae2-4dff-431f-bbe7-7514d8902d0e'
ORDER BY `validFrom` DESC
LIMIT 1) AS sub UNION ALL
...
```

When I analyze it it yields the following result:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 7.936409288,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "<derived2>",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 342,
      "r_rows": 171,
      "r_table_time_ms": 0.166444022,
      "r_other_time_ms": 0.15610209,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "materialized": {
        "query_block": {
          "union_result": {
            "table_name": "<union2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,114,116,...>",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "r_loops": 0,
            "r_rows": null,
            "query_specifications": [
              {
                "query_block": {
                  "select_id": 2,
                  "r_loops": 1,
                  "r_total_time_ms": 0.128546205,
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "<derived3>",
                    "access_type": "ALL",
                    "r_loops": 1,
                    "rows": 2,
                    "r_rows": 1,
                    "r_table_time_ms": 0.013479732,
                    "r_other_time_ms": 0.016444884,
                    "filtered": 100,
                    "r_filtered": 100,
                    "materialized": {
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 3,
                        "r_loops": 1,
                        "r_total_time_ms": 0.102809089,
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "aircraftAssignment",
                          "access_type": "range",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "aircraft_assignment_aircraft_idx",
                            "aa_valid_from_index"
                          ],
                          "key": "aa_valid_from_index",
                          "key_length": "115",
                          "used_key_parts": ["aircraft_id", "valid_from"],
                          "r_loops": 1,
                          "rows": 5,
                          "r_rows": 3,
                          "r_table_time_ms": 0.040696599,
                          "r_other_time_ms": 0.030328298,
                          "filtered": 100,
                          "r_filtered": 33.33333333,
                          "attached_condition": "aircraftassignment.aircraft_id <=> 'd27feb20-7de9-4500-b0a5-9965aa9fb80a' and aircraftassignment.deleted_at is null and aircraftassignment.valid_from <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "query_block": {
                  "select_id": 4,
                  "operation": "UNION",
                  "r_loops": 1,
                  "r_total_time_ms": 0.049281287,
                  "table": {
                    "table_name": "<derived5>",
                    "access_type": "ALL",
                    "r_loops": 1,
                    "rows": 2,
                    "r_rows": 1,
                    "r_table_time_ms": 0.002692682,
                    "r_other_time_ms": 0.006288156,
                    "filtered": 100,
                    "r_filtered": 100,
                    "materialized": {
                      "query_block": {
                        "select_id": 5,
                        "r_loops": 1,
                        "r_total_time_ms": 0.035126031,
                        "table": {
                          "table_name": "aircraftAssignment",
                          "access_type": "range",
                          "possible_keys": [
                            "aircraft_assignment_aircraft_idx",
                            "aa_valid_from_index"
                          ],
                          "key": "aa_valid_from_index",
                          "key_length": "115",
                          "used_key_parts": ["aircraft_id", "valid_from"],
                          "r_loops": 1,
                          "rows": 9,
                          "r_rows": 1,
                          "r_table_time_ms": 0.013620362,
                          "r_other_time_ms": 0.009586675,
                          "filtered": 0.100033343,
                          "r_filtered": 100,
                          "attached_condition": "aircraftassignment.aircraft_id = 'de648ae2-4dff-431f-bbe7-7514d8902d0e' and aircraftassignment.deleted_at is null and aircraftassignment.valid_from <= '2022-03-20 22:59:59.999'"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
...
```

As visible the r_total_time_ms of the middle blocks are as expected ca. equal by the sum of the times deeper. The main difference between the two tables is that the position table uses an integer as the id and the aircraft table uses an uuid but I don't think that this should have a real impact on the performance and even then I would  expect the integer id to be the better performing one.

The total count of the rows in the tables is the following:
position: 1691
positionInfo: 790
aircraft: 1735
aircraftAssignment: 8997

As seen positionInfo even has less rows than aircraftAssignment but performs worse.

Any ideas what could cause the worse performance? I would prefer to let the query be as it is and tweak things on the indices if possible.